# SOCKET.IO analogy in angular application (with rx.js)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, frontend

I am developing angular(2) application.
And I want to update view when data changed in back end.

```
  getData() {
      return this.http.get("some url")
      .map(result => result.json());
  }
```

How can I develop listener in my component, which will be listen and updating view?

Comment: Do you mean you don't want to use socket.io when you say you are looking for an analogy? Do you have write access to the code on the server side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, two solutions depending on what you are able to do:

### 1 - You have write access to the server's code

Then you can implement the websocket support on your server and then use a tool like https://github.com/ohjames/rxjs-websockets to automatically wrap the socket events in rxjs observables.

### 2 - You don't have write access to the server's code

Well, in this case, you will have to do a regular polling of the server. Which would look something like that:

```
Rx
  .Observable
  .timer(0, 1000) // once every second
  .mergeMap(_ => this.http.get("/url").map(json => result.json()))
```

If the server is well implemented (and you send the right headers), it might send you back a `304` http code from which you can deduce that nothing happened since your last call, and you can filter out those cases.

Hope it helps